# CSS - fill bar differently

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to fill simple html bar, but not as usually when we are doing progression bar.

I want for example bar with value max = 30 and value min = 1 (~month). Then when I've got this, I want to fill it by green and red color. I want when I tell with my data from angularJS , that 5,10,12 and 16 is a red color, fill this fragment, rest is for green.

I've searched a lot, but still got nothing. Thanks

Comment: (_For `ngRoute` / `ui.router`_) [`ng-bootstrap`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar/examples) / [`ui.bootsrtap`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#progressbar) have [Progress bar](https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/cvxuJ), if that's what you are looking for

Comment: Well it's not what I am searching. I want to fill bar with red color, but for example - fill bar with values from 1-10 and from 90-100. from 10-90 color should be green

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: So I thinks it's okay, when I am asking about way to resolve this :) Just never did that, so I had no clue about the answer and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui.bootstrap` can let you stack [progress bars](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#progressbar). Here is an example with random values:

```js
angular.module('demo',['ui.bootstrap']).controller('ProgressDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
 

  $scope.randomStacked = function() {
    $scope.stacked = [];
    var types = ['success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];

    for (var i = 0, n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1); i < n; i++) {
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
      $scope.stacked.push({
        value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 1),
        type: types[index]
      });
    }
  };

  $scope.randomStacked();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="ProgressDemoCtrl">

    <h3>Stacked example: <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="randomStacked()">Randomize</button></h3>
    <uib-progress>
      <uib-bar ng-repeat="bar in stacked track by $index" value="bar.value" type="{{bar.type}}"><span ng-hide="bar.value < 5">{{bar.value}}%</span></uib-bar>
    </uib-progress>

  </div>
</div>
```